Dynamic routes error in Vercel after Nextjs update: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/future/route-modules/pages/vendored/contexts/amp-context'
I'm getting this error in Vercel preview for dynamic routes using getStaticPaths and getStaticProps  after upgrading Nextjs from 13.4.8 to 14.2.4. Fallback paths are working.
"engines": {
"node": "18.17",
"npm": "9.x"
},
⨯ Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/future/route-modules/pages/vendored/contexts/amp-contextyour text' Require stack: /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js /var/task/node_modules/next/head.js /var/task/node_modules/next-seo/lib/next-seo.js /var/task/.next/server/pages/_app.js /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js /var/task/_next_launcher.cjs /opt/rust/nodejs.js at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15) at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:11:28979 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27) at /opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11508 at Function.Wt (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11878) at Q.e.<computed>.K._load (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11478) at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19) at u.require (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:11:29083) at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js:30:34) { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js', '/var/task/node_modules/next/head.js', '/var/task/node_modules/next-seo/lib/next-seo.js', '/var/task/.next/server/pages/app.js', '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js', '/var/task/next_launcher.cjs', '/opt/rust/nodejs.js' ], 
I've updated dependencies and tried downgrading to other Nextjs versions but to no avail. I'm not quite sure how to reproduce this either.
